# Aggregate nested objects mongodb

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, aggregation-framework, aggregate

Could you please help me to write some sort of aggregation query using mongodb.

I have next data structure.

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        shouldPay: true,
        users: [
            {
                id: 100,
                items: [{...}],
                tags: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
            },
            {
                id: 100,
                items: [{...}],
                tags: ['b', 'c', 'd']
            },
            {
                id: 100,
                items: [{...}],
                tags: ['c', 'd']
            }
        ],

    }
]
```

In result I want to get something like that:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        shouldPay: true,
        user: {
            id: 100,
            items: [{...}],
            tags: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
        }

    }
]
```

The main idea is to select a specific user that has "a" letter or list of letters ['a', 'b'] in tags.

Comment: @astro noup, that's another case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below aggregation

Use [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) at the starting of the pipeline to filter out the documents which don't contain `"a"` and `"b"` in `tags` array. And then use [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with [**`$setIsSubset`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/) to filter out the nested array.

[**`$arrayELemAt`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to return the specified element from the array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "users.tags": { "$in": ["a", "b"] }}},
  { "$project": {
    "users": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$users",
          "cond": { "$setIsSubset": [["a", "b"], "$$this.tags"] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: good, but your code will fail in case if we will start matching with an array of elements. let's imagine that you will have something like this { "$in": [['a', 'b', 'c'], "$$this.tags"] }

Comment: You haven't mentioned that in question. Please clarify your question. Do want to match with single element or with an array

Comment: sorry about that

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: pretty good idea to use $setIsSubset, but I tried to use it previously, and it doesn't work with the nested objects.

Comment: Don't know how did you use that. What's now ? Take a [look](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Gu-SLfdnZr0)

Comment: thanks, yes it works

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183852/discussion-between-bob-dylan-and-anthony-winzlet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $unwind along with $filter:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
      {
        $unwind: "$users"
      },
      {
        $match: {
          "users.tags": "a"
        }

      }
    ])
```

Result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "id": 1,
    "shouldPay": true,
    "users": {
      "id": 100,
      "tags": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c",
        "d"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: not the best idea, as can be the situation that you had more than 20k records and unwind produce a big amount additional records per document